# Optaplanner : Optimal count of number of steps for termination

Tags: optaplanner

I am setting my solver local search phase termination strategy based on total number of steps. I see that when I set number of steps as 80,000 it terminates inside 30 mins. So I set it around 200,000 and expect it to terminate within 2-3 hours.

However, even after a day it hasn't terminated. I then ran it with DEBUG logs and found that after around 90,000 steps, the time taken per steps starts increasing and around 100,000 mark it just does not take any new steps.

What could be causing this? If it has exhausted all the steps does it not terminate automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Late Acceptance (the default algo) and Simulated Annealing the number of steps per minute varies greatly depending on how long it's been running. In the beginning they are fast stepping, because they are far more likely to accept a move (which triggers going to the next step) and over time they become slow stepping, because they are far less like to see a move that they like as they become near optimal.

Tabu Search is pretty consistent n in the number of steps per minute.

Comment: Oh okay. I will try Tabu Search also. Can you also explain why that is the case? From the documentation, I cannot find any mention of this behaviour.

Comment: Wouldn't you always use Late Acceptance then? When is Tabu Search better?

Comment: step speed is mostly not correlated to solution quality (= score)

Comment: Got it. How can I decide the correct termination strategy then? I don't want to base it on time since it compromises the reproducibility of the solution.